# javascript function referencing and a parameter passed explaination

Tags: jquery, angularjs, javascript

I  have this code in a code base I am looking at and I am trying to figure out whats going on.

I understand that MyDefinedVariable_1 is getting the instance of some file.js. However I want to know

1- why is MyDefinedVariable_1 referenced at the end of MyDefinedVariable_2 like })(MyDefinedVariable_1). What purpose that serve?

2- What is _super? It seems to me some query thing but not sure

```
var MyDefinedVariable_1 = require(‘somefile.js);

var MyDefinedVariable_2 = (function (_super) {
..……….
…………    

})(MyDefinedVariable_1);
```

thanks

Comment: you are calling the function inline and passing a parameter to it

Comment: we need a little more code, from what you posted it seems like `MyDefinedVariable_2` will probably inherit from `MyDefinedVariable_1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyDefinedVariable_2` is being set to the results of defining and then calling a function.  That function takes a parameter called `_super`.  When the function is being called, `MyDefinedVariable_1` is being passed in as the function parameter (so within the function, wherever it says `_super` the value used will be whatever is assigned to `MyDefinedVariable_1`).

Here's a simpler example:

```
var a = 1;
var b = (function(myParam){
  return myParam + 4;
})(a);
```

After running this, `b` will be 5.  When defining `b`, we called the function that adds 4 to whatever was passed in (`myParam`), and what we passed in was `a`.  And `a` was assigned 1. So `b` will be 5.